# How to get parameter descriptions in WADL-generated documentation

Tags: wadl

Martin, I've been trying to use your wadl documentation generation code to document a REST interface from Javadoc annotations and I've been unable to get it to document the parameters to the method / query parameters. I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. I supply Javadoc comments to the method in the usual manner, for example:

```
    /**
 * Gets an Account object by id.
 * @param req the HttpServletRequest encapsulating this GET request
 * @param q the id of the Account object to be returned
 * @param xid optional transaction id associated with this request
 * @return an AccountModel object corresponding to the requested it. 
 * If not found an APIException is thrown.
 */
@GET @Path("/id")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public AccountModel getAsXML_JSON(@Context final HttpServletRequest req, 
        @QueryParam("q") String q,
        @QueryParam("xid") String xid)
```

I'm sure there's something obvious that I'm missing. As written above, the comment "Gets an Account object by id" makes it into the resourcedoc.xml file, and from there to the application.wadl file, but none of the parameter definitions work.
When I add

```
 * @annotationDoc {@name q} {@doc the id of the Account object to be returned}
 * @annotationDoc {@name xid} {@doc optional transaction id associated with this request}
```

I can see the descriptions of the parameters in the resourcedoc.xml file, but it looks like they're appearing in the wrong place, and nothing shows up in application.wadl file.
Any help you can give will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question, the problem was that resourcedoclet could not find the definition of the QueryParam or Context classes. It therefore inserted QueryParam into the generated XML but did not include the name/value pair identifying the parameter the QueryParam referred to. This resulted in the generated html including the method description but not the parameter descriptions since the parameters the QueryParam referred to could not be located.
The fix was simply to include jsr311-api-1.1.1.jar in the classpath for the Javadoc command invoking the resourcdoclet.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to your pom.xml